# Angular setting title depending on activated route and its parents

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

My goal:
I would like to globally listen for router NavigationEnd events and change the title of the web page depending on the route custom data.

Current code (in app.component.ts):

```
this.router.events.pipe(
  filter((ev) => ev instanceof NavigationEnd),
  map(() => this.activatedRoute),
  map((route) => {
    while (route.firstChild) route = route.firstChild;
    return route;
  }),
  filter((route) => route.outlet === 'primary'),
  mergeMap((route) => route.data),
).subscribe((event) => this.title.setTitle(event['title']));
```

got from [this tutorial](https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/dynamic-page-titles-angular-2-router-events)

The above code works, but is not elegant at all, look at the needed routing configuration:

app-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'user',
    loadChildren: () => import(`./user/user.module`).then(m => m.UserModule),
    data: { title: "Pagina Utente" }
  },
  {
    path: 'admin', loadChildren: () => import(`./admin/admin.module`).then(m => m.AdminModule),
    data: { title: "Pannello Admin" }
  },

  { path: '**', component: HomeComponent },
];
```

admin-routing.module.ts:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', component: AdminPanelComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'users', component: UsersComponent,
        data: { title: 'Pannello Admin: Utenti' }
      },
      {
        path: 'comuni', component: ComuniComponent,
        data: { title: 'Pannello Admin: Comuni' }
      },

    ]
  }
];
```

As you can see, i already specified that the /admin route should have "Pannello Admin" as a title, but i need to write it again and again for each of its children routes.

I tried to fix this problem by changing the app.component.ts code to this:

```
this.router.events.pipe(
  filter((ev) => ev instanceof NavigationEnd),
  map(() => this.activatedRoute),
  map((route) => {
    let title = route.data['title'] || '';
    while (route.firstChild) {
      route = route.firstChild;
      title+= route.data['title'];
    }
    return route;
  }),
  filter((route) => route.outlet === 'primary'),
  mergeMap((route) => route.data),
).subscribe((event) => this.title.setTitle(event['title']));
```

I expected this code to work and set my title to the concatenation of the data['title'] property of the matched routes. However it doesn't work and just gives out empty titles (the data['title'] are always undefined for some reason)

Comment: In the router module you can hook up to nav end there, then you can use an eventservice to notify subscribers. And you're right that's some ugly code to me.

Comment: Thanks for the new lead, how would i hook up to the navigationEnd event from the router module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Angular 14, this can be handled natively.

So, you can write the routes like below.

app-routing.module.ts

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'user',
    loadChildren: () => import(`./user/user.module`).then(m => m.UserModule),
    title: "Pagina Utente" // <--
  },
  {
    path: 'admin', loadChildren: () => import(`./admin/admin.module`).then(m => m.AdminModule),
    title: "Pannello Admin" // <--
  },

  { path: '**', component: HomeComponent },
];
```

admin-routing.module.ts:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', component: AdminPanelComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'users', component: UsersComponent,
        title: 'Utenti' // <--
      },
      {
        path: 'comuni', component: ComuniComponent,
        title: 'Comuni' // <--
      },

    ]
  }
];
```

The default `TitleStrategy` will result in showing the title of the end node of the routing tree. So, you'll see only `Utenti` when you visit `/admin/users` for example.

You can set `'Pannello Admin: Utenti'` to the `title` property instead of `'Utenti'`, but overriding `TitleStrategy` should be more effective.

You can see a simple sample code to override the strategy in `Overriding The Global Title Strategy` section of [the article here](https://dev.to/brandontroberts/setting-page-titles-natively-with-the-angular-router-393j)

To build titles like `Pannello Admin: Utenti` from the routes above, the custom `TitleStrategy` would be like:

```js
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class ConcatTitleStrategy extends TitleStrategy {
  constructor(
    private readonly title: Title
  ) {
    super();
  }

  override updateTitle(routerState: RouterStateSnapshot): void {
    const title = this.concatTitle(routerState.root, '', ': ');
    if (title) {
      this.title.setTitle(title);
    }
  }

  private concatTitle(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, title: string, separator: string): string {
    if (!route)
      return title;

    const sub = route.data ? this.getResolvedTitleForRoute(route) : undefined;
    if (sub) {
      title = `${title}${separator}${sub}`;
    }

    title = this.concatTitles(route.children[0], title, separator);

    return title;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export class AppRouterModule {
   constructor(private router: Router, private eventService: EventService) {
      this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
         if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
            this.eventService.StartNavigationSpinner();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

I put navigation event subscriptions into the AppRouterModule itself, then when a particular event happens I send it to an eventService which all loaded components listen to list this:

```
  this.EventService.NavigationStartEvent.subscribe(() => {
         if (this.showGlobalSpinner) return;
         this.showGlobalSpinner = true;
      });
```

The eventservice is a Service which looks like this:

```
export class EventService {
   NavigationEndEvent = new EventEmitter();
   NavigationStartEvent = new EventEmitter();
...
```

All the parsing is done in the app.router module an merely will send an event to whatever title changed subscription is loaded?  It could be any loaded component.

If the rewrites are happening, too often, it's because the pages are reloading by angular's routing/render cycle. Of suspicion is the the loadChildren config in routes.

I think what you want is main page to load one time and only change title if a single child page changes. I believe this means you need another ngRouterOutput.  Angular documentation is dizzying on this concept. The idea that children can exist on any page.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving my problem by using this code in my app.component.ts constructor:

```
this.router.events.pipe(
  filter((ev) => ev instanceof NavigationEnd),
  map(() => this.activatedRoute),
).subscribe((activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) => this.title.setTitle(activatedRoute.snapshot.data['title'] || 'Gestionale Incarichi'));
```